# Custom ROS message with unit8[] in python!

Tags: ros, rospy, ros-kinetic, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a `PacketMsg.msg` as follows in my package:

```
uint8[] buf
```

I would like to decode `/topic` with this sample python script;

```
import rospy
from ouster_ros.msg import PacketMsg

def cb(msg):
    rospy.loginfo('len_msg: {}, type_msg: {}'.format(len(msg.buf), type(msg.buf)))
    rospy.loginfo('msg: {}'.format(msg.buf)) 

def main():
    rospy.init_node("my_sub")
    rospy.Subscriber('/topic', PacketMsg,cb)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the output printed in terminal:

```
[INFO] [1579270050.540915]: len_msg: 49, type_msg: <type 'str'>
[INFO] [1579270050.541343]: msg: ��H?�~�a�B��`����g=��?M��
```

whereas, `$ rostopic echo /topic` returns:

```
buf: [47, 185, 250, 245, 155, 0, 0, 0, 54, 238, 166, ....................... , 23, 154, 0, 0]
```

Does anybody know how to change such  `<type 'str'>` to a list for further usages?

Cheers,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341940/custom-ros-message-with-unit8%5B%5D-in-python!/) by [Farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25360/farid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 165 on 2020-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Python a `str` can be iterated and indexed in the same way as a `list`: `msg.buf[i]`

Each 8-bit character can be converted into a number using `ord()`.

To get the same result as you see on the console you can do a list comprehension: `[ord(c) for c in msg.buf]`

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [v.leto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37009/v.leto/) on 2021-11-26**:
Hi! I have the same problem, I get a series of letters instead of number but I am coding with c++. How can I solve the same issue? Many thanks